# Button doesn't update data get from SharedPreference

Tags: android, button, sharedpreferences, android-sharedpreferences

I use some codes to update data in onActivityResult method of Activity:

```
                //save state
                editorUserInfoSharedPreferences.putString("userType", productId);
                editorUserInfoSharedPreferences.putInt("paymentStatus", 1);
                editorUserInfoSharedPreferences.commit();
                editorUserInfoSharedPreferences.apply();

                int paymentStatus = userInfoSharedPreferences.getInt("paymentStatus", 0);
                String userType = userInfoSharedPreferences.getString("userType", "");
                Log.e(TAG, "paymentStatus 1700: "+ paymentStatus);
                Log.e(TAG, "userType 1700: "+ userType);
```

The data in log is correct. But after that, I hit a button and get data from sharePreference:

```
    int paymentStatus = userInfoSharedPreferences.getInt("paymentStatus", 0);
                String userType = 
 userInfoSharedPreferences.getString("userType", "");
                Log.e(TAG, "paymentStatus 1532: "+ paymentStatus);
                Log.e(TAG, "userType 1530: "+ userType);
```

The data in log is old data.
Here is my log:

```
E/MAINACTIVITY: paymentStatus 1700: 1
E/MAINACTIVITY: userType 1700: monthly_0
....
E/MAINACTIVITY: paymentStatus 1532: 0
E/MAINACTIVITY: userType 1530: 0
```

How can I fix that? Thank u in advance!

Comment: You should use either commit or apply

Comment: is there a problem if i use both of them?

Comment: Yes, one of this is synchronous and one of is asynchronous. Also android suggest use apply()(synchronous) if your are working on multiple thread and if you are working on main.thread you can go with commit.

Answer (score 0):

Could you paste your code to init: editorUserInfoSharedPreferences & userInfoSharedPreferences. One thing I can guess you are using 2 difference sharepreference objects.

Comment: userInfoSharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(CURRENT_USER_INFO_FILE, MODE_PRIVATE);
        editorUserInfoSharedPreferences = userInfoSharedPreferences.edit();

Answer (score -1):

Initialize your userInfoSharedPreferences in your onActivityResult after performing commit on editorUserInfoSharedPreferences.

You are getting old values because you are using old object of your sharedpreference.